# Oxwall transfer domain host

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, cpanel, smf-forum

I am using Oxwall, trying to transfer my files from one domain/host/server to another I used  softaculous to install Oxwall and make databse/cron/etc.

If I transfer the files to a new host/domain what should I do with:

```
define('OW_DB_HOST', '???????');
define('OW_DB_PORT', ??????);
define('OW_DB_USER', '??????');
define('OW_DB_PASSWORD', '??????');
define('OW_DB_NAME', '??????');
```

http://docs.oxwall.org/faq:how-to-transfer-my-site-to-another-hosting

I am trying to set up a XAMPP with phpmyadmin, etc, would it be helpful? or would it be easier to create database using cPanel in new host? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just remove `ow_includes/config.php` and import old database.